# What does "recorder players are most comfortable in sharp keys" mean?

Tags: meaning

> "Recorder players are most comfortable in sharp keys"

At first sight of the sentence I mistakenly thought "recorder player" was something like a recorder set, but I soon realized that might be a performer whose performances are recorded.(I am not quite confidence with my grammar and tenses here:))

But, still, I am a bit confused about the meaning of this sentence.

Does it mean "a player in recording will do his best in sharp keys" , or "for playing in sharp keys, recorder players are the most suitable among all kinds of players"? Which understanding is more reasonable?

Comment: As a matter of practice, please try to put your question – and the sentence you are asking about – in the body of your question. Keep titles brief, and don't omit the sentence in question from the question text itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recorder is a woodwind instrument:
[image]

And at least in your speaker's opinion musical key signatures like B, E, A, D, G and F# are easier to play on the recorder.

Comment: Wow, what a mistake I made!

Comment: @dennylv It's a pretty understandable mistake.  I'd bet there are native speakers who would misinterpret "recorder players" at first.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the statement, but I can maybe see where it's coming from: to play a sharp note, you just half-cover the respective hole. To play a flat, you need to figure out what the next lower note is, and half-cover that. (And of course, in actuality, there are all sorts of exceptions, especially if you're playing a baroque-tuned recorder.)